# Dynamically load new button from XML

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, button

I'm trying to load a new button for each XML element in an XML Doc. I need to make a new instance of the button for each xml node in the document. The code below works as far as making a new button goes, but the button has a custom Attribute called "money" that keeps getting overwritten. So I'm trying to find some method to dynamically name the button as well, E.G. button (Dynamic Name) = new button();

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.
xmlDoc.Load("XML.xml");
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    string money = elemList[i].Attributes["www"].Value;
    string itemName = elemList[i].Attributes["money"].Value;

    button LB = new button();
    LB.Text = money + itemName;
    LB.money = itemName;
    LB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    x += 25;
    y += 25;
    LB.Click += new EventHandler(item_click);
    this.Controls.Add(LB);
}
```

Comment: Is `button` your custom class deriving from `System.Windows.Forms.Button`? Who overwrites `money` and why? How would having a name set help? Have you tried setting the `Name` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
button LB = new button();
LB.Text = money + itemName;
string tmp_itemName = itemName;
LB.money = tmp_itemName;
```

this works as long as `.money` is NOT static...